# What are the security implications if systemd is not restarted after it has been updated?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, system-compromise

My understanding is that `systemd` is the parent process for all other processes running on Linux.

If `systemd` has been updated on production devices such as servers and the service is not restarted, what are the security implications?

What are the common attack vectors for `systemd` to signal it must be restarted?

The article on [systemctl daemon-reexec](https://serverfault.com/questions/805745/reboot-or-systemctl-daemon-reload-for-changes-to-etc-systemd-system-conf) suggests that a package update already performs restart `systemd`.

This suggests there is no requirement to restart `systemd` even though the output below displays it has been updated and may be using deleted files.

```
PID  | PPID | UID  | User    | Command       | Service       | Files                      
-----+------+------+---------+---------------+---------------+----------------------------
1    | 0    | 0    | root    | systemd       |               | /usr/lib64/libkmod.so.2.3.3
907  | 1    | 0    | root    | systemd-udevd | systemd-udevd | /usr/lib64/libkmod.so.2.3.3
2284 | 1    | 1000 | user    | systemd       |               | /usr/lib64/libkmod.so.2.3.3
2285 | 2284 | 1000 | user    | systemd       |               | /usr/lib64/libkmod.so.2.3.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still running the old binary, having all its vulnerabilities. You can restart Systemd without reboot using the [Manager Lifecycle Commands](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#Manager%20Lifecycle%20Commands): `systemctl daemon-reexec` should be enough after a package upgrade.

The details depends entirely on the vulnerabilities found in the specific version and is information that will become obsolete too quickly to be meaningful on a Q/A site. You should check

- the release notes (for [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+changelog), [Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/systemd) e.g. stable [`systemd_232-25+deb9u8`](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/s/systemd/systemd_232-25+deb9u8_changelog)) and
- [*Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures* (CVE)](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=systemd). Last vulnerabilities were memory corruptions (CVE-2018-16864, CVE-2018-16865) and an information leak (CVE-2018-16866). (You could also notice that there's [CVE-2018-16888](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-16888) that hasn't *currently* been fixed in [Debian stable](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2018-16888).)

If you aren't able to evaluate whether these vulnerabilities have security implications in your situation, just upgrade your packages regularly and restart the services.

Comment: Thanks. What are the implications of its compromise and what are the types of exploits?

Comment: Thanks. What are the common attack vectors that would demand that `systemd` requires it is restarted? Does `systemd` restart itself when it is upgraded or does it require manual intervention?

Comment: That depends on the distribution. A package manager is responsible for automatically restarting the upgraded services. However, the `daemon-reexec` is safe to run if you are unsure.